# Scroll UIView with its contents

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibutton, uiimage, scrollview

I am new to iPhone,

I have a `shelf` image and i had loaded this image in my `View` then i have created a some button and added to the `View`

**See snapshot:**
[image]
But the problem is, I want to `scroll` my `shelf` image so i kept `shelf` inside `scroll` so shelf scrolls properly but button inside a view does not scrolls.

I want to scrolling in both image and in the button as well.

**How to achieve this ? or Any tutorial available for this ?**

***Any help will be appriciated.***

Comment: post your code, how did you populate the scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add yourButton view to yourScrollView as subview.

```
[yourScrollView addSubView:yourButton];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: I think you are write, but my image also does not scroll with code above, where i am doing mistake ?

Comment: How did you define scrollView? or The image size is less. Check it

Comment: I have taken scroll view in `xib` file with outlet connection

Answer (score 2):

You have placed the buttons on superview, isnt it? Place them on your shelf, and they will scroll. Also, use to post your code when asking a question, it will ease the analyze.

Comment: Buttons are dynamic so i can't place buttons in my shelf, i need to add them separately, see my Code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is use your `Shelf.png` as the background of your scroll view and then set the buttons according to image and the problem is solved as the background is scrolling with all the scroll in scroll view

Happy Coding :)

**EDIT 1**

For setting the backgroundImage of scrollView

```
[catScroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"small_tab_.1.png"]]];
```

The real image is

[image]

And the resulted scroll view is  (as i need it as horizontal scrollView)

[image]

Comment: ok will put some code in update of my answer just wait for some time :)